# How to define default maven repositories for spark-submit packages

Tags: maven, apache-spark

When I execute my *spark-shell* or *spark-submit* command

```
spark-shell --repositories https://myrepository.com/release 
--packages com.myrepo:spark-helpers:0.1
```

works perfectly and I can use my own code.

As there are several config files like *spark-defaults.properties* and *spark-env.sh* I assumed that you can configure this settings somehow.

What I found is that you should use *spark.jars.ivy* in *spark-defaults.properties* for defining a *ivy repository* [*link-to-source*](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) but I don't see a point why I should use *ivy* when *spark-submit* supports maven by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked, and the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment) on `spark.jars.ivy` has since changed, but I'll try and answer anyway.

One use of `spark.jars.ivy` is for resource isolation across applications on the cluster.

If 2 spark applications running on the same cluster require 2 different (and possibly conflicting) versions of the same package, you could isolate the 2 jars by passing `spark.jars.ivy=/ivy/cache/for/app1` and `spark.jars.ivy=/ivy/cache/for/app2`

The jars will be downloaded in the according directory, so the jars from various runs will be isolated and won't conflict with each other.